# What if someone's testimonial account changes and contradicts itself?

Tags: evidence, trial

I am curious to know what happens if someone gives testimony in Court 2 times, and there are contradictions or discrepancies between the two statements.

As an example, how might the following two statements be reconciled or handled in Court?

> *Statement #1*: I was jogging along a trail when all of a sudden in
> became foggy, I was able to see a man who threatened a lady and
> punched her.  The other 3 people with me couldn't see anything, but
> they did hear the lady yell.  Once the man ran away, I fainted and
> within a few minutes I woke up.
>
> *Statement #2*: I was jogging along a trail when all of a sudden in
> became foggy, I was able to see a man who threatened a lady and
> punched her.  The other 3 people could see what I saw, but they didn't
> hear anything.  Once the man ran away, I fainted and after 1 hour I
> woke up.

Assume this is the *only* testimony of the event.

Would this witness's testimony still hold up in court?

Answer (score 5):

> **Yes. It will hold up in court.**
>
> *IMHO, there is no difference in the admissible portions of the two testimonies.*

#### "Few minutes" vs. "One hour" is immaterial

The difference between "a few minutes" and "one hour" IMHO is ***immaterial*** given:

1. the witness was unconscious and
2. say, between 45 and 60 minutes would match both descriptions of the time interval.

#### What other people saw and heard is hearsay

Testimony about what other people saw and heard (with a few notable exceptions) is ***[hearsay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearsay)*** and not allowed into evidence because it is generally ***unreliable*** and not subject to ***cross-examination***.

So after the rejection of the hearsay portions, there is no difference in the admissible portions of the two versions.

#### Qualification

By "hold up in court," I mean it will be allowed as evidence. The weight and veracity of the testimony would be determined by the (judge or) jury after [cross-examination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-examination).

Comment: The differing hearsay accounts could be introduced to show that the witness should not be believed because the witness remembers it poorly. It is up to the jury to weigh the evidence and arrive at the truth.

Comment: @Viktor this is interesting. It makes sense. Is there a rule which establishes this?

Comment: Yep. Two arguments actually. Hearsay is defined by rule 801 of the federal rules of evidence as an out of court statement offered to prove the truth of the matter asserted. In this case this statement is not offered for its truth content, but to show it differed from a later recollection. Additionally, 801 d)1) could be used to argue that the statement is admissible.